# Toggle button not working for navigation drawer for the first time

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I saw similar questions but answers are no use. That's why I post it.
Here is how I setup my Drawer at `FragmentDrawer.java`.

```
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
    containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    toolBar = toolbar;
    onDrawerOpen();
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.drawer);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });
    mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onDrawerOpen();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is `onDrawerOpen` method.

```
private void onDrawerOpen() {
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout,
            toolBar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            toolBar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
        }
    };
}
```

And call from `MainActivity` like this.

```
drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, mDrawer, mToolbar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you first initialize the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` by calling `onDrawerOpen()`, you call `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false)`, which disables the indicator, and causes any clicks to be routed to the Navigation click listener. Upon the first click, `onDrawerOpen()` is called again, which re-initializes the toggle, and it then works as expected.

It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do, but if you just want the standard toggle behavior, move the toggle initialization to the `setup()` method, and remove the `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled()` and `setToolbarNavigationClickListener()` calls.

```
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
    containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    toolBar = toolbar;

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout,
                                              toolBar, R.string.drawer_open,
                                              R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            toolBar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
        }
    };

    mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.drawer);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yap, @Mike, this code is not what I wrote and I've no idea too. I'll try your answer and then gonna make your question correct one.

Answer (score 3):

in your Xml file you must change visibility of NavigationView visible

```
   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```